# Subclass type as function parameter

Tags: arrays, swift, subclass

I have an array of objects. The array contains different subclasses.

```
class MainClass {
}

class SubClass1:  MainClass{
}

class SubClass2:  MainClass{
}

var arrayOfObjects = [SubClass1(), SubClass2(), SubClass1()]
```

I want to include a function that removes all objects that are a specific subclass type.

```
arrayOfObjects = arrayOfObjects.compactMap { $0 as? Subclass1 }
```

How can I use the subclass type as function parameter?

```
func removeObjectsOf(type: //??) {
arrayOfObjects = arrayOfObjects.compactMap { $0 as? type }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter using `type(of:)`

```
let filtered = arrayOfObjects.filter { type(of: $0) == SubClass1.self }
```

or if you want to write it as a function

```
func filter(_ array: [MainClass], with classType: MainClass.Type) -> [MainClass] {
    array.filter { type(of: $0) == classType }
}

filter(arrayOfObjects, with: SubClass1.self)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass this kind of type as a generic type parameter:

```
func removeObjectsOf<T: MainClass>(type: T.Type) {
    arrayOfObjects = arrayOfObjects.compactMap { $0 as? T }
}
```